# What is the song played at 6:54 in the 5 episode of Parasyte - the Maxim?

Tags: theme-song, parasyte

Did anyone know? It's the scene when Kana looks into the eye of Shinishi, I really love this song, and it's not in the OST.

Answer (score -1):

I found it myself, it's Migi Theme.

Comment: There is not actually a song by that name on either of the Parasyte OSTs ([one](http://vgmdb.net/album/48700), [two](http://vgmdb.net/album/53967)).